# Is it possible to work with an offline folder with automatic network synchronisation?

Tags: windows, networking, sync, offline-files

Right now, I'm working primarily on a network folder on a Samba server in a Windows network.

I want to switch to work with a local copy, preferably with automatic synchronisation. I thought about using Windows Offline Files, but as far as I understand it they will only access the local files if the network folder is currently unavailable, and more importantly, I want to work with real local paths (one of my Visual Studio extensions doesn't handle network files correctly, neither UNC paths nor mapped drives.)

Is it possible to have a local copy of my network folder contents with constant automatic synchronization in both directions?

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for a relatively simple answer, try DropBox: http://www.dropbox.com

Comment: Can I have two dropbox folders in one network which will get updated over the network? I thought this is only for completely remote computers with internet synchronization - I mean, I only have one computer here

Comment: They'll just both synchronize over the Internet if you install DropBox on both computers. It should work great as long as you don't have more than a few GB. Your comment that you only have one computer, however, seems to contradict the entire premise of the question.

Comment: The Samba server is a Debian computer, but think of it as a simple NAS drive. There's one computer on which I work. I'm accessing the files on the server with it, but want to access a local mirror of those files so that I don't have to use network files.

Answer (score 1):

You could also use a platform-independent distributive revision control tool like [Mercurial](http://mercurial.selenic.com/). That way, you avoid putting your sensitive data in the cloud (and at reach of the NSA).

Here is the [Wikipedia entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mercurial) with some more information and an [excellent guide](http://hgbook.red-bean.com/read/) to get you started.